# adding interactive waiting bar in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have added a waiting bar in matlab by using the following commands, but it want to make a modification.

```
h = waitbar(0,'Algorithm is running Xth simulation');
N = 30;
 for i = 1:N
   ...

 waitbar(i / N)
end;
close(h)
```

Now, I want to change the waitting bar in such a way that in each loop it shows that "Algorithm is running ith simulation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [The Fine Manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitbar.html) of `waitbar`, you can pass it a string with an updated message. Formatting a string in which you want to insert some numbers is done the easiest with [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html). Example:

```
n = 10;
h = waitbar(0, sprintf('Starting %i simulations', n));
for i=1:n
    pause(1); % pretend to do some work, your simulation code goes here
    waitbar(i / n, h, sprintf('Finished the %ith simulation', i))
end
pause(1) % wait a little bit before closing it.
close(h)
```

Comment: How I can add a title for waiting bar window? (e.g. "Filter simulation")